# Retrieve substrings from individual components of an array in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

For a command such as

```
grubby --info=ALL
```

the output received is something of the sort -

```
index=3
kernel="/boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-80.el8.x86_64"
args="ro crashkernel=auto resume=/dev/mapper/cl-swap rd.lvm.lv=cl/root rd.lvm.lv=cl/swap rhgb quiet"
root="/dev/mapper/cl-root"
initrd="/boot/initramfs-4.18.0-80.el8.x86_64.img"
title="CentOS Linux (4.18.0-80.el8.x86_64) 8 (Core)"
id="d7fe995b9d09403896e1e56a2b02a947-4.18.0-80.el8.x86_64"
index=4
kernel="/boot/vmlinuz-0-rescue-d7fe995b9d09403896e1e56a2b02a947"
args="ro crashkernel=auto resume=/dev/mapper/cl-swap rd.lvm.lv=cl/root rd.lvm.lv=cl/swap rhgb quiet"
root="/dev/mapper/cl-root"
initrd="/boot/initramfs-0-rescue-d7fe995b9d09403896e1e56a2b02a947.img"
title="CentOS Linux (0-rescue-d7fe995b9d09403896e1e56a2b02a947) 8 (Core)"
id="d7fe995b9d09403896e1e56a2b02a947-0-rescue"
```

I can pipe this output into an array, to try and refer to each block individually -

```
mapfile -t my_array < <(grubby --info=ALL )
```

However, this saves each element as a separate string in `my_array`, such as

```
 printf '%s\n' "${my_array[0]}"
```

Output -

```
index=3
```

Perhaps I can access these elements for comparison based on regularity of offset (7 in this case for each subitem in subsequent blocks).

However, I'd like to retrieve the string value of these array components, doing a
`printf '%s\n' "${my_array[1]}"` gives me
`kernel="/boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-80.el8.x86_64"` from which I'd like to get the value...

Also, if someone could suggest a better way, such as by accessing the value individually in each file, maybe something like -

```
cd /boot/loader/entries
for filename in $(find -type f -name '*.conf'); do
//Access this field
```

Not sure how to do it, though..

Comment: If there is a better way, such as what I've mentioned at the bottom of the question, or any other, I'll be happy to change. Not very familiar with shell scripting...

Comment: The issue is your data. You have `index=3` and `index=4` and what follows each are the same `name=value` pairs where `name` is the same. Since bash does not provide 2D associative arrays -- that choice is out. (you can attempt to simulate -- but it gets messy). If you don't store anything and simply retrieve the values, then you can provide the index as a parameter and retrieve the value for any name you like that follows the index. `awk` would be the choice, but given you have less than a few hundred lines, a shell script would not be prohibitively slow.

Comment: It doesn't help that `'='` appears in multiple places in the `args=` line...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin  Ah, am slightly confused. I understand the part about the array, and the explanation of not using it, but am not sure how else I can access the individual records, and fields within those records..Should I access the files individually and delve into them, or is there a way to access (without storing or array) with the command? Sorry if it seems a silly question. The `conf` files are in `/boot/loader/entries/`.

Comment: Parameter expansions (with substring removal). For example: `while read -r line; do ...` and lets say you want separate the line at the 1st `'='`. You can remove from the left through the first `'='` in `line` with `value="${line#*=}"` -- `$value` now holds what is on the right side of the `'="`. To get the name, you just remove from the right to the last(first) `'='` with `name="${line%%=*}"`. But `$value` may contain double-quotes as characters which you can remove with `[ "${value:0:1}" = '"' ] && value="${value:1:$((${#value}-2))}"`. (which picks the substr between 1st and last char)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Understood. Thank you. If you write it out as an answer, I'll accept it as one...Is there a feedback given as to why question is voted down or voted for closure? I'd like to improve if provided a feedback.

Comment: Okay, give me a sec. -- there is quite a  bit there `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subject to the comments about your output of `grubby` containing multiple `index=` lines where the `name=value` pairs have the same names under each index, the general way you handle parsing values from string variables in bash is with a *parameter expansion (with substring removal)*. I say "general" way because the following parameter expansions are also provided in POSIX shell so your script will be portable to other shells. (bash provides an additional number of expansions that are bash-only)

A summary of the parameter expansions with substring removal are:

```
${var#pattern}      Strip shortest match of pattern from front of $var
${var##pattern}     Strip longest match of pattern from front of $var
${var%pattern}      Strip shortest match of pattern from back of $var
${var%%pattern}     Strip longest match of pattern from back of $var
```

(**note:** pattern can contain the normal globbing characters such as `'*'`, and `front` above is the same as"from the left" and `back` is "from the right" which you will see used interchangeably)

For your output above, you can loop over the lines separating the `name=value` pairs into `name` and `value`. Since the names repeat under each index, you can't use an associative array `array[name]="value"` directly or you will only end up with the last values. (you can save the `index=X` and use `array[X name]="value"`, but that gets messy when you want to retrieve things)

You have another caveat with the `args` name that contains `'='` within the `value` portion. (which you would want to use the `${var#pattern}` form to isolate `name=value` based on the first `'='` from the front (left))

As an example, you could redirect the output of `grubby` directly as you have done using a *process substitution* (bash-only) or redirect it to a file and read line from the file with something similar to:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do
    name="${line%%=*}"          ## strip from the right to last =
    value="${line#*=}"          ## strip from left through first =
    ## if double quoted -- remove double quotes
    [ "${value:0:1}" = '"' ] && value="${value:1:$((${#value}-2))}"
    printf "name: %-8s  value: '%s'\n" "$name" "$value"
done < "$1"
```

**Example Use/Output**

Reading your `grubby` data from a file would result in:

```
$ bash readnameval.sh info
name: index     value: '3'
name: kernel    value: '/boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-80.el8.x86_64'
name: args      value: 'ro crashkernel=auto resume=/dev/mapper/cl-swap rd.lvm.lv=cl/root rd.lvm.lv=cl/swap rhgb quiet'
name: root      value: '/dev/mapper/cl-root'
name: initrd    value: '/boot/initramfs-4.18.0-80.el8.x86_64.img'
name: title     value: 'CentOS Linux (4.18.0-80.el8.x86_64) 8 (Core)'
name: id        value: 'd7fe995b9d09403896e1e56a2b02a947-4.18.0-80.el8.x86_64'
name: index     value: '4'
name: kernel    value: '/boot/vmlinuz-0-rescue-d7fe995b9d09403896e1e56a2b02a947'
name: args      value: 'ro crashkernel=auto resume=/dev/mapper/cl-swap rd.lvm.lv=cl/root rd.lvm.lv=cl/swap rhgb quiet'
name: root      value: '/dev/mapper/cl-root'
name: initrd    value: '/boot/initramfs-0-rescue-d7fe995b9d09403896e1e56a2b02a947.img'
name: title     value: 'CentOS Linux (0-rescue-d7fe995b9d09403896e1e56a2b02a947) 8 (Core)'
name: id        value: 'd7fe995b9d09403896e1e56a2b02a947-0-rescue'
```

So that is one way to approach the separation. The other would be to use `awk` which allows the same approach to simulating 2D arrays using a `','` to separate multiple index values (see `SUBSEP` in `man awk`). However, if you can get what you need without storing all values -- then you eliminate the simulated 2D array issue altogether.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Appreciate your answer, and the explanation. I am trying it out now. I shall ask if I've questions. Thanks again.

Comment: `value=${value//'"'}` remove all double quotes ?

Comment: Sure there are many options there. I was originally wanting to keep the script POSIX, but using the indexing expansion defeated that purpose. The expansion for global substitution would  be fine -- and simpler along with the explanation of the implied substitution with nothing where the closing `'/'`, e.g. `value=${value//'"'/}` is omitted.

Answer (score 2):

In bash, it is possible to create an associative array, say named `grubby`,  and access its elements like `${grubby[index,key]}`. For instance `${grubby[3,kernel]}` should expand to `/boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-80.el8.x86_64`.

Example script:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A grubby

while read -r line; do
    if [[ $line = index=* ]]; then
        index=${line#index=}
        continue
    fi
    [[ $line = *=* ]] || continue
    key=${line%%=*}
    value=${line#*=}
    value=${value#\"}
    value=${value%\"}
    grubby[$index,$key]=$value
done
# Examples
echo "3,kernel = ${grubby[3,kernel]}"
echo "4,root   = ${grubby[4,root]}"
```

The output of the `grubby` command should be redirected to the script:

```
grubby --info=ALL | ./script
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was quite useful.